# Bisection search : Why cant my low be equal to 0

Tags: python

So the code below is basics of Bisecton search :

```
low = 0.0
high= x #This is the sqaure root we are trying to find 
ans=(high+low) / 2 #Here we take half of the range between 1 and 25

while abs(ans**3 - x) >= epsilon:
    print("low = " + str(low) + " high ="+ str(high) + " ans = " + str(ans))
    #Note here if the gap is bigger than epsilon, this means the answer has not been found yet, we want to see what
    #the low and the high are 
    numGuesses += 1
    if x > 0 :
        if ans**3 <x :
            low = ans #Note here although we set that >0.01 as answer has been found, we need it to rinse and repeat the process 
                      # of halving , when tis too small, the low become ans, which means we take away the lower half
        else:
            high = ans #This is when ans**2 > x , which has gone too far, hence we take away the higher halve
        ans = (high+low)/2
        #We see this entire loop, only breaks if abs(ans**2 - x) < epsilon, which mean its close enough 
        
    else :
        if ans**3 >x :
            low = x
            high = ans
        else:
            low = ans
            high = 1
            #Note here it cannot be 0

        ans = (high+low) / 2 

print("number of guess is " + str(numGuesses))  
print(str(30000-numGuesses)+" times less run than Guess and check.")
print(str(ans) + "is close to sqaure root of" + str(x))
```

At the at the third else ,# Note here it cannot be 0, there is a high=1.
When high =1, it runs pretty good, however when high =0, it runs forever for somereason.
From my understanding it could be because -1 is involved, which would break since -1**3 = -1, which might cause the loop to run forever. But when high = 0, I dont understand why it breaks like this. Appreciate the explaination.

Comment: What is ```epsilon```?  Please include the actual output and the expected output.   Have you traced what happens when high = 0?

Comment: Are you doing square roots (as per your comments and string literals) or cube roots (as per your code)?